# EfCore REST-API: For stateless application, should query always be AsNoTracking

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

REST is stateless and EfCore by default tack entities when queried. I believe EfCore performs better without-track.

In web-api, for any Http_Get, I am using `dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking();` to get `IQueryable` instead of `dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();`.
However there are cases where I have to track entity, e.g. when updating disconnected entity.

Is it a good approach to query without-track for all Http_GET request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a good approach to use `.AsNoTracking()` for read-only queries.

See this [documentation entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking):

> No tracking queries are useful when the results are used in a read-only scenario. They're quicker to execute because there's no need to set up the change tracking information. If you don't need to update the entities retrieved from the database, then a no-tracking query should be used.